# TypedDict class is an Incompatible Type for function expecting Dict

Tags: python, mypy, typeddict

I created the below TypedDict class;

```py
class Appinfo(TypedDict):
    appid: int
    extended: dict[str, Any]
    config: dict[str, Any]
    depots: dict[str, Any]
    ufs: dict[str, Any]

class SteamAppInfo(TypedDict):
    appid: int
    data: dict[str, Appinfo]
```

In my application I'm passing a variable of this class to a function expecting a dict;

```py
    def dict_get_key_list(data: dict[str, Any], key_list: list[str]) -> Any:
        """returns a dict value or None based on list of nested dict keys provided"""
        try:
            return reduce(operator.getitem, key_list, data)
        except KeyError:
            return None
```

The code itself runs fine as for all intents and purposes, SteamAppInfo is a dictionary. However, MyPy is giving me the error below;

```
error: Argument 1 to "dict_get_key_list" of "Utils" has incompatible type "SteamAppInfo"; expected "Dict[str, Any]"
```

How do I get MyPy to recognise that what's being passed is a dictionary without having to list all of the TypedDicts I've created as possible variable types or setting the variable type to Any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#typeddict):

> A `TypedDict` object is not a subtype of the regular `dict[...]` type (and vice versa), since `dict` allows arbitrary keys to be added and removed, unlike `TypedDict`. However, any `TypedDict` object is a subtype of (that is, compatible with) `Mapping[str, object]`, since `Mapping` only provides read-only access to the dictionary items:

So use `data: Mapping[str, Any]` instead of `data: dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: Great - that sorted it! Thanks.